Where to put Gradle publishing logic in Kotlin project?
I have a Kotlin open source project. I am confused about what to do with a publishing logic in my gradle build file when I will upload my open source library to github. I'm using the org.gradle.maven-publish plugin. I've rarely seen open-source projects that also include publishing logic within them (or I haven't looked good enough). How should I approach this so I'm doing it properly?
I was suggested that my question is answered in this question. But it does not answer it. For clarification: I am asking whether it is okay or not to upload your source code to your open source project on GitHub where gradle build files contain publishing logic. I am not asking how to publish via Gradle Plugin. I am asking if uploading your publishing logic to GitHub is safe to do, because I have not seen publishing logic of other open source projects on GitHub that use Gradle. So if it is not safe, how to do it?

This question is similar to: Publish custom jar output with gradle?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
